# Neron-Severi group $= H^{(1,1)}(X,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, holomorphic-bundles

Where does my confusion arise from? I am getting $H^{(1,1)}(X,\mathbb{Z})=NS(X)$, the Neron-Severi group, however in any reference I don't find this remarkable thing.

Let $X$ be a Kahler manifold. Using the exponential sequence one obtains a homomorphism $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*)\rightarrow H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$. This is associating to a holomorphic line bundle its Chern class $c_1$.

If we take any connection $D$ on a holomorphic line bundle $L$, if we do $D\circ D$ and then take its class in $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ we get a curvature form independent of the choice of the connection. Multiplying by $-i/(2\pi)$ we run into $c_1(L)$ when identifying $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ as a subspace of $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$. This is a theorem. The last in particualr shows that the image of $c_1$ is always $(1,1)$ form.

On the other hand, the map $H^1(X, O_X^*)\rightarrow H^{(1,1)}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is surjective by the Lefschetz theorem.

So  $\operatorname{im} c_1 =H^{(1,1)}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ ? The group of Neron-Severi $NS:=H^1(X,O_X^*)/\ker c_1\cong \mathrm{im} c_1$

Answer (score 3):

Of course, you should be writing $H^{(1,1)}(X)\cap H^2(X,\Bbb Z)$ when you use your shorthand. And you need $X$ compact Kähler. But ... You're almost right: The Lefschetz Theorem assumes $X$ is a projective variety, does it not?

Comment: Hmm, the proof on Wiki does not?

Comment: If you want to get the result that every line bundle corresponds to a divisor on $X$, you need $X$ projective to guarantee a meromorphic section.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see if it is used in the sheaf cohomology proof.

Comment: This proof gets you a line bundle, but Neron-Severi is divisors!

Comment: possibly a quite stupid question: why it is allowed to identify $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ as a subgroup of $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ here as the OP has remarked? or in other words why is the map $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ induced by canonical inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{C}$ of local constant sheaves on $X$ an injection between $2$-th cohomology groups?

Comment: @user738714 This map needn't be an injection if there is torsion in $H^2(X,\Bbb Z)$. From the line bundle side, you can see this with flat bundles (whose curvature forms vanish, and so the De Rham representative is the zero form).

Comment: This argument using flat bundles I not fully understand. We want to show that $\phi:H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ is injective if there is no tosion. Assume that that's wrong. We find a non trivial class $[a] \in H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ whichs image $\phi[\alpha]$ vanishes in  $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$. How do you now use the properties of flat bundles to show that $[\alpha]$ was already trivial? Can we conclude that if $\phi[\alpha]$ is trivial then $[\alpha]$ was already represented by a curvature form induced by a flat bundle? Why? Or did I misunderstood your argument?

Comment: No, I was explaining that torsion elements map to $0$, even if you think about line bundles. The straightforward way to prove that the non-torsion elements inject is to use the universal coefficient theorem: $H^2(X,\Bbb C) \cong H^2(X,\Bbb Z)\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb C$. Sheaf cohomology is, after all, isomorphic to singular cohomology, etc.

Comment: sorry for repeated annoying but I still confused on that issue. If $H^2(X,\Bbb Z)$ has no torsion, then it is the job of universal coefficient theorem to show that $\phi:H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ is injective using $H^2(X,\Bbb C) \cong H^2(X,\Bbb Z)\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb C$. I understand. But in previous comment you mentioned the flat bundles (characterized by the property that their curvature forms vanish, and thus also their De Rham representative as the curvature is by definition a cycle in the $2$nd component of the chain-complex $\Omega^*(X)$). My question is

Comment: why do a flat bundle and it's induced curvature provide an example for a torsion element in $H^2(X,\Bbb Z)$? Simply because it is zero in $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ by using UCT or is there a more "intuitive" reason behind it.

Comment: Flat bundles by definition admit a connection with zero curvature. It's a theorem that they all can be constructed from representations of (finite) $\pi_1(X)$. You can do some reading on this.

Comment: so the point is that by your thoerem (do you know a recomendable reference for it or it's name?) there exist certain group homomorphism (since it has to respect the order) $\pi_1(X) \to H^2(X,\Bbb Z)$ which hits all elements which arise as representatives of curvatures induced by flat bundles, right?

Comment: I have looked up a bit for the theorem you was talking about. You talked about the Ambrose-Singer theorem, right? It gives a bijection between flat $G$-bundles over connected manifold $M$ and representations ${\displaystyle \rho :\pi _{1}M\rightarrow G}$. What I still not understand if this construction is functorial in appropriate sense? namely if we assume that $\pi_1(M)$ is finite, that is al elements has finite order. How this fact gives us rise for torsion elements in $H^2(X,\Bbb Z)$?